# Cannot import local package installed with `pip install -e .`

Tags: python, import, pip, package

I have a package under development and also a few scripts that import this package. I am trying to install the package with developer mode using `pip install -e .` but then I cannot import it in my scripts.
I have the following file structure where `singlepixel` is a package I am developing.

```
├── setup.py
├── singlepixel
│   ├── acquisition.py
│   ├── metadata.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── scripts
│   ├── script1.py
│   └── script2.py
```

My `__init__.py` has the following structure:

```
from .acquisition import init, setup, acquire, disconnect
from .metadata import MetaData, AcquisitionParameters
```

And my `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='singlepixel',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='gbm',
    package_dir={"": "singlepixel"},
    packages=find_packages(where="singlepixel"))
```

From my understanding, I should be able to do a simple import statement in my `script1.py`such as `from singlepixel import *`, however it does not work and I get the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'singlepixel'
```

Moreover it seems that I am not able to import the package anywhere even though I am using an anaconda environment. From my understanding, I should be able to import my package anywhere when using this environment just like any other package installed with `pip install`.

Comment: Try `pip install .` and check if it installs succesfully

Comment: It installs succesfully but I still get that same error. But anyways I wanted to install with `-e` to be able to make changes in the package as well.

Comment: great question, i was fighting this for hours... thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have packages inside `singlepixel/`, that directory itself is a package. So remove

```
package_dir={"": "singlepixel"},
```

and change

```
packages=find_packages(where="singlepixel"))
```

to

```
packages=find_packages())
```

Comment: you saved me from going crazy... thanks